# AJAX call to php database Google maps markers

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps

I am trying to make connection with my database

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'pictures.php', data: "", dataType: 'json', success: function (rows) {
            for (var i in rows) {
                var row = rows[i];

                var id = row[0];
                var name = row[1];
                var pic = row[2];
                var lat = row[3];
                var lon = row[4];
                $(addMarker( id + name + pic + lat + lon));
            }
        }
    });
```

This is pictures.php:

```
<?php

$dbname = 'test'; //Name of the database
$dbuser = 'root'; //Username for the db
$dbpass = ''; //Password for the db
$dbserver = 'localhost'; //Name of the mysql server

$dbcnx = mysql_connect("$dbserver", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bezienswaardigheden");

$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($query) )
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $data );
exit

?>
```

This is the function addMarker:

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(pt);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pt,
        icon: icon,
        map: map
    });
    var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: info,
        maxWidth: 300
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        if (currentPopup != null) {
            currentPopup.close();
            currentPopup = null;
        }
        popup.open(map, marker);
        currentPopup = popup;
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function () {
        map.panTo(center);
        currentPopup = null;
    });
}
```

I cant see markers on google maps with this code. The maps works perfect, but I want markers for places I fill in the database :( AJAX don't make connect with pictures.php.

Comment: In what way does this fail?  Is the AJAX request sent to the server?  What is the server's response?  When you debug this, where does it go wrong?

Comment: You need 3 parameters for `addMarkers()` => `lat`,`lng`,`info` and you call that function in a strange manner with strange values?? `$(addMarker( id + name + pic + lat + lon));`